# Echo with ansii colors doubles my text (zsh,mac)

Tags: macos, zsh, osx-mavericks

Im using iTerm2 on Mavericks. `$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`. When I print this in command line:

```
echo -e "\e[0;36m xxx \e[0m"
```

the console beeps on error and the output is:

```
xxx "  xxx
```

in correct color. Any ideas on what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely reason for this behaviour is that you have some settings in your `~/.zshrc` that update the terminal title to contain the currently running command line without quoting special characters, like `\e`.

Most likely the line that actually updates the title looks something like that:

```
print -n -- "\e]2; $commandline \a"
```

Instead of `\e]2;` it may also be `\e]0;` and instead of `print -n` it could be `echo -en`.

The important part is that this is the same command that is used to print to the terminal, but anything between `\e]2;` and `\a` (the "bell" character) will go to the terminal title instead of being printed into the terminal.

That is unless `$commandline` contains some special characters like `\a` or `\e`. In these cases a part or all of the output may be printed to the terminal instead of the title.

In your case the first `\e` in the `echo` interrupts the setting of the terminal title and everthing after that goes to the terminal. That is, the first part of your output - `xxx "` - comes from a failed setting of the terminal title and the second part - `xxx` - is the actual output of `echo`.

---

To prevent this behaviour, you need to properly quote anything you want to send to the terminal as title.

In my `~/.zshrc` I have something like this to set the terminal title after cleaning up the command line:

```
settermtitle () {
    # save the first argument in commandline if given, else use empty string
    local commandline="${1:-}"
    # remove special whitespaces (newline, tab, vertical tab, etc)
    commandline=$(print -nr -- "$cl" | tr "\n\t\v\f\r" " ")
    # quote print specials
    commandline=${(V)commandline}
    # quote backslashes
    commandline=${commandline//\\/\\\\}

    print -n -- "\e]2; iTerm2 - $commandline\a"
}

preexec_title () {
    settermtitle "$1"
}

add-zsh-hook preexec preexec_title
```

First I replace any whitespaces by space characters. Then I make non-printable characters visible. And lastly I quote any backlashes remaining to avoid any problems with escaped characters - like `\e` - in `$commandline`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Problem at my place was setting the terminal title to current command like: `printf "\e]1; $PWD:t:$(history $HISTCMD | cut -b7- ) \a"` in `(post/pre)exec` function.